# Control of Nuclear Fission

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, binding-energy

What is it precisely which prevents current technology in nuclear fission from controlling the size of fission products; in other words, why is it not feasible, presuming that such an approach would permit the translation of binding energies to heat in nuclear fission reactions, to create lighter more manageable fission products, thus rendering that fission technology relatively safe?  Further, if this constraint is due to the electrical neutrality of the neutron, what prevents the induction of a manageable charge or manipulation of the neutron magnetic dipole moment?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the periodic table of elements , you will see that there are about 118 of them, with a lot of [isotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_nuclides) to be sure.

These are not marbles stuck together. They are neutrons and protons held together by the quantum mechanical interactions of the [strong nuclear force,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) in stable energy levels or unstable ones . The nuclear shell model , analogous to the atomic solutions for electromagnetism, can describe them, and various other models can explain the content and why after interactions or fissions they will go to alphas, or neutrons or gamma rays, and other fragments.

So fragmentation into other nuclei  is not something that can be controlled  and fine tuned externally, i.e. **the strong force is not tunable the way the electromagnetic one is.**

> Further, if this constraint is due to the electrical neutrality of the neutron, what prevents the induction of a manageable charge or manipulation of the neutron magnetic dipole moment?

Neutrons are characterized by a weak decay lifetime of a ~15 minutes and cannot be stored or "manipulated" in the sense you require.

The only choice is to look at the [binding energy curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy) and the periodic table of elements . That is why fusion is pursued in new machines, smaller number of neutrons and protons and better chance that the solutions may yield less radiation.

Comment: The question then is what is it which ACTUALLY prohibits such manipulation or 'tuning' of the SNF, particularly given the REAL sense in which is inextricably related to charge and spin. Eventually, protons and neutrons, and indeed these latter-day marbles, 'quarks', must eventually be understood as and shown to be oscillatory states of each other within a common substrate, only predominantly existing in the form of these various theoretically defined identities, p, n, u/d-quarks. It is readily conceivable that requisite control of the SNF might one day be achieved with magnetic fields/EMF.

Comment: again, the strong force is not tunable because of the large coupling constants of the strong interaction. No, it cannot be conceivable, because unification of forces happens at very high energies in a GUT model,  where all , strong weak electromgnetic have the same mathematical behavior. High energies defeats the purpose  because  there are no nuclei at those energies.( 10^25 eV) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_unification_energy

Comment: Again, the high energies of existing GUT conceivably follow from a misconstruction inherent in that model itself. While it is no doubt impossible to deconstruct fissile material into very small isotopes, it may reasonably be argued that the configuration in distribution of what is identified in extremely limited empirical contexts (of collisions) as the SNF may be transformed through precise displacement of its components or local polarisation (using magnetic force), to permit the elaboration of smaller isotopes. A better model is required: e.g. with a singular basis for coupling constants.

Comment: " a better model" there is none at the moment, the standard model of particle physics has not been falsified, so any new model has to include it, because it is based on innumerable measurements/data.

Comment: A new model certainly would explain the basis of QED and the SM. The SM, abstraction upon abstraction that it is, is a practically adequate model until it attempts to imagine the possibility suggested, which as you point out it is forced to deny in the terms you indicate. Thank you. In this case a 'better model' might be one capable of finding leverage, a chisel instead of a sledgehammer to prise rather than crack open 'matter'. Possibly though it is correct that it takes more energy to control this horrific process than could usefully be gathered by it. The future model...perhaps another day.